# Adminhtml - default settings

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

Is it possible to set column default value to display selected type of block?
[image]

what I mean is if the page is opened for the first time "slide" is already selected as a default?

Field definition:

```
        $this->addColumn('is_slide', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Slide/Block'),
        'index'     => 'is_slide',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => array(
            0 => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Block'),
            1 => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Slide'),
            2 => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Banner')
        ),
    ));
```

and my _construct()

```
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('cmsBlockGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('block_identifier');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('is_slide'=>'Slide'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. You can do it by setting `DefaultFilter`.
In order to do this go to your `grid.php` and add below mentioned code to your `__construct()` function.

```
$this->setDefaultFilter(array('slider_block'=>'slide'));

ie: $this->setDefaultFilter(array('column_name'=>'value'));
```

Comment: Tried this but it won't work. Field name is "is_slide" and possible values 0,1,2 which are block, slide,banner :(

Comment: My _construct:
 parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('cmsBlockGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('block_identifier');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
 $this->setDefaultFilter(array('is_slide'=>1));

Comment: try **is_slide=>slide**

Comment: Nope, does not do the job :(

Comment: are you using an option array to display this slide,block and banner?

Comment: option array, check my updated post on top

Comment: hah, yes, you was right: but no string but number of option works

Comment: yeah value should be there. glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

The answer was: 
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('is_slide'=> 1));
and it works. 
Thank you